# Calculating gas a payable function call of smart contract in ethersjs

Tags: ethers.js, gas-estimate

I am doing something with this logic. But how do I calculate how this will cover different gas amount on **different EVM chains**

```js
let gasLimit = 210000;
const { gasPrice } = await provider.getFeeData();
let total = gasLimit * gasPrice;
let value = (balance - BigInt(total)).toString();


await contractInstance.depositAll({
    value,
    gasLimit: gasLimit,
    gasPrice: gasPrice
});
```

> What I want to do is pass the entire balance to the function to cover the gas price of the chain

Comment: The `native gas cost = gasLimit * gasPrice`; `value` can then be set to `current account balance - native gas cost` if you want the account to give away all remaining funds(i.e. that remain after funding the tx gas cost)